# Set up mock API server for isolating frontend-backend dependencies

Tags: api, mocking

Our application is a API based one wherein the frontend relies on REST API calls to the back end. This sometimes creates a problem wherein the frontend team can't move forward unless the backend API's have been implemented since they invariably progress at different speeds. Is there a way to set up a server so that the front-ent can work independently regardless of the backend status ?

Comment: There are mocking frameworks out there that can be used with unit tests that can help with this.  It depends on what language you're using, though.

Comment: The backend is implemented in Java and ideally I would like to setup the mock server responses in Java. The front end is Javascript written in Node.Js

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit of an old post but I created a tool just for this purpose and I thought I should share it for anyone who stumbles across it.

It's called Interfake and you can find it at https://github.com/basicallydan/interfake. I frequently use it for prototyping APIs which haven't been built yet, in fact that is my main use of it. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

A common solution that we work with is as follows :

FE and BE contracts/APIs are agreed upon and the back end apis are mocked. 
The BE rest APIs use a filter that we configured. 
For all the apis that are ready, the filter redirects to the correct api and for all the apis that are mocked the filter redirects to the mock api.

So transparent to the FE team as the BE team is building and completing more apis, they just update the map that the filter looks and and automatically the back end apis get invoked as soon as the BE team is ready to open it up.

So the flow is as follows :

```
FE ->BE Rest API Server 
      |API Filter->(for apis updated in the map as complete)-->server/port with actual api  
      |------------->(for apis that are still being mocked) --> server/port with mock
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If am understanding correctly, in your case the BE Dev's (or QA's) begin by writing mock responses in a separate project and then begin work on the actual implementation.

Comment: No we do not use a different project. It is in the same project. If we have three apis, A, B, C. We have the mocks of A, B, C. All the mocks are also part of the project and may be served from a different port or different url. If A gets complete, it is setup in a map that a filter picks up, so this will now be redirected to a url or port that is hosting the latest and best implementation.

Comment: We use JAVA or Nodejs for API and FE is nodejs.